# Show that the given elliptic equation has a radially symmetric solution.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the following problem (Gilbarg, Trudinger: "Elliptic PDEs of second order", problem 3.8):

Consider the equation
\begin{equation}
L_n u \equiv a^{ij}D_{ij} u = 0,\quad a^{ij} = \delta^{ij} + g(r)\frac{x_ix_j}{r^2},\quad i,j= 1,\dots,n
\end{equation}
Show that $L_n u=0$ has a radially symmetric solution $u=u(r), r\neq 0$ satisfying the ordinary differential equation
\begin{equation}
\frac{u''}{u'} = \frac{1-n}{r(1+g)}
\end{equation}

Do anyone have any hints on where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $v(x)=u(|x|)=u(r)$, where $r=|x|$. Calculate $L_nv(x)$ and substitute it in the equation $$L_n v(x)=0$$

If you do all this tedious calculation right, in the end of it, you will get the result you want.

Comment: I presume you mean calculate $L_n v(x)$ and then substitute $L_n u(x)= 0$? In this case if find that $L_n v(x) = -\frac{g(r)}{r}D_i u(x)\left(\frac{x_i x_j}{r^2}\right)^2$ for $i\neq j$, and zero otherwise. Is there some argument I am missing, or is it safe to assume I have made a mistake?

Comment: I think you are making an confusion. Gilbard and Trudinger uses the Eisntein summation convention, i.e. $L_n v(x)=a^{ij}(x)D_{ij}v(x)=\sum_{i,j=1}^n a^{ij}(x) D_{ij}v(x)$. Hence, you have to calculate all second derivatives and then, you have to sum up all you got.